# including class as member in struct

Tags: c++, c, oop

I have to add a class object as member within a c struct.

Is there any prohibition doing this.

Regards,
iSight

Comment: You have tagged your question both C and C++. In C++ it is certainly possible as struct is just a kind of class. In C it is of course impossible.

Comment: As struct is more prone to "C" i tagged with C as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You CAN have a C++ class member in C, but it needs to be seen as a `void*` in the C point of view, so as the C can handle it fine.

This technique is called [Opaque Pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer).

Answer (score 4):

I'll assume you're talking about C++, since there is no concept of a "class" in C - although you certainly can have a `struct` as a member of another `struct`.

Apart from one unimportant detail, `class` and `struct` are identical, and both are often referred to as "class types". Anything you can do with a `class` (such as having a member of class type), you can also do with a `struct`.

If you're interested, the only difference is the default accessibility of members and base classes; `public` for `struct`, and `private` for `class`.

Answer (score 0):

No there is not. Check out this example:

```
#include<iostream>

class Foo {
    public:
        Foo() {
            this->i = 1;
        }
        int i;
};

struct Bar {
    Foo foo;
};

int main() {
    struct Bar bar;
    std::cout << bar.foo.i << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: However, depending on the makeup of the class, the struct may loose POD status which will restrict some operations that could have otherwise been done on the struct.

Comment: What do you mean by POD? Can you clarify the term for me? Never heard of it.

Comment: No What i mean is the reverse of the case you put over here. class within struct. Ok let this be a c++ project, to be precisely.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the struct is just used in C++ code, there's no problem. However, if the struct is passed to C code, bad things might happen (destructor not called when struct is freed/deleted).

If you don't see anything like extern "C" in the declaring file, you are probably safe.